# Show masked area on top of camera widget

Tags: graphics, flutter

I'm trying to implement a credit card reader (using some API). For the user to take a picture of the card, I'm presenting the camera preview widget full screen. I would like to mask out an area so the user centers the card there.

[He're an illustration of what I have in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgMKY.png)

I was wondering how this masking could be accomplished in flutter? Currently I'm just drawing a `BoxDecoration`, but that's missing the semi transparent, greyed out area.

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8 / 1.55,
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: 2.0,
        style: BorderStyle.solid),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0))),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this for the time being but it is a very inefficient solution and I am sure there must be a better solution that I too would like to know.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: P(),
            child: CameraPreview(controller),
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: Clip(),
            child: CameraPreview(controller)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
class P extends CustomPainter{
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawColor(Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstOut);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

}
class Clip extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    print(size);
    Path path = Path()
    ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(Rect.fromLTWH(10, size.height/2-120, size.width-20, 240), Radius.circular(26)));
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: how can we cut out the clipped area and display in another page?

Answer (score 1):

I now just went with a custom BoxPainter and first draw the background, then the card area and finally blend the layers together to 'cut out' the center part.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CardDecoration extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback onChanged]) {
    return _CardPainter();
  }
}

class _CardPainter extends BoxPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    final clearPaint = new Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
    ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut;

    final bgPaint = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(150, 0, 0, 0)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final borderPaint = new Paint()
    ..color = Colors.white.withAlpha(120)
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 3.0;

    final rect = offset & configuration.size;
    final cardWidth = 0.8*rect.width;
    final cardHeight = cardWidth/1.55;

    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height), clearPaint);

    canvas.drawPaint(bgPaint);

    canvas.saveLayer(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height), clearPaint);
    canvas.drawRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(0.1*rect.width, (rect.height-cardHeight)/2, 0.9*rect.width, (rect.height+cardHeight)/2, Radius.circular(8)), bgPaint);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.drawRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(0.1*rect.width, (rect.height-cardHeight)/2, 0.9*rect.width, (rect.height+cardHeight)/2, Radius.circular(8)), borderPaint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can try with columns, rows, and containers :).

```
Widget getMaskCard(BuildContext context) {

    Color _background = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: 1,
                color: _background,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: _background,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 180,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: _background,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: 1,
                color: _background,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt2Yj.jpg)